# SQL Error - Column does not exist (in SELECT as)

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I am joining two tables:   **breeds** + **breed_characteristics (bc)**

But I'm getting the following error:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "val" does not exist LINE 11

I'm not sure what's wrong, here is my SQL:

```
SELECT                                                                      
  breeds.*,                                                                 
  CASE bc.user_val                                                          
    WHEN NULL THEN bc.value                                                   
     ELSE (bc.value + (bc.user_val/2))/2                                       
   END AS val                                                                
  FROM                                                                        
  breed_characteristics bc       
  INNER JOIN breeds ON breeds.id = bc.breed_id                                
  WHERE bc.characteristic_id = 45                               
  AND val BETWEEN 4 AND 5                              
  ORDER BY val DESC
```

(Executing this query on Postgres through Active Record)

Comment: The error is correct.  You need to use a subquery or CTE in order to use a value defined in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Gordon:  

I'm confused as to why - Is this due to the inner join?

Answer (score 10):

You can't use expression alias `val` in `where` clause like that.

It's because there is an order in which SQL is executed specified in the SQL standard. Here, the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before `SELECT` and hence, the `WHERE` clause is not aware of the alias you created in the `SELECT`. The `ORDER BY` comes after the `SELECT` and hence can utilize aliases.

Just replace the alias with the actual case expression like this:

```
SELECT                                                                      
  breeds.*,                                                                 
  CASE bc.user_val                                                          
    WHEN NULL THEN bc.value                                                   
     ELSE (bc.value + (bc.user_val/2))/2                                       
   END AS val                                                                
  FROM                                                                        
  breed_characteristics bc       
  INNER JOIN breeds ON breeds.id = bc.breed_id                                
  WHERE bc.characteristic_id = 45                               
  AND CASE WHEN bc.user_val is NULL THEN bc.value                                                   
     ELSE (bc.value + (bc.user_val/2))/2                                       
   END BETWEEN 4 AND 5                              
  ORDER BY val DESC
```

However, you can use alias in `order by` clause.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you explain why the where clause won't accept it?  

I needed to modify your answer as it wasn't working with a case argument in the WHERE clause.   I changed it to:
...                                
>                            
  AND CASE                                                           
    WHEN bc.user_val IS NULL THEN bc.value                                                   
     ELSE (bc.value + (bc.user_val/2))/2                                       
   END  
...

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying.  

Now I'm confused why the parser evaluates the WHERE clause before the SELECT.  It seems counterintuitive, as the WHERE could reference the columns aliased in the SELECT.

Answer (score 3):

One option to avoid restating the `CASE` expression in multiple places is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT b.*,
           bc.characteristic_id,
           CASE WHEN bc.user_val IS NULL THEN bc.value
                ELSE (bc.value + (bc.user_val / 2)) / 2                                       
           END AS val                            
    FROM breed_characteristics bc       
    INNER JOIN breeds b
        ON breeds.id = bc.breed_id
) t
WHERE t.characteristic_id = 45 AND
      t.val BETWEEN 4 AND 5                              
ORDER BY t.val DESC
```